# MySQL -> Dropdown and back

Tags: php, mysql, html

I just started my 'journey' with this kind of programming and I've got a problem. I was searching for similar issues but haven't found satisfactory answer here. So, here it comes:
What I'm trying to do is to load some data from database to my `dropdown` menu on `html` page. I managed to did it this way:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!(isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) || $_SESSION['loggedIn'] == true))
    {
        header("location:index.php");
        exit();
    }

    include 'connection.php';
    include 'func.php';

    $arajka=getRdyDev(); 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p> blablabla <br/> </p>

        <select>  
        <?
        foreach ($arajka as $a)
        {
            echo  "<option value=\"" .$a['id']. "\">" .$a['id']. "_" . $a['name'] . "</option>";
        }
        ?>
        </select>

        <p> <br/>blablabla</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Well, looks like a spaghetti to me, but w/e, that's my first `PHP` code ever. In my database I've got columns called `ID` `NAME`, `LAT`, `LON`, `BUSY`. In `getRdyDev()` I return array of devices that are not busy at the moment. In `<select>` I print only `ID` and `NAME`. Now I want to get `LAT` and `LON` when user clicks on specific `<option>` and I've got no idea how to do this. (I don't want to reload whole page but only, I don't know, `<div>` with some `textfields` maybe?). In the next step I will use that data (to be exact: `id`) to insert some other data to other table in my database. Any suggestions please?

Kind regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give custom data attributes to the option tag and store the lat and long values over there something like

```
<?
foreach ($arajka as $a){
       echo  "<option data-lat=$a['lat'] data-long=$a['long'] value=\"" .$a['id']. "\">" .$a['id']. "_" . $a['name'] . "</option>";
}
?>
```

and in Jquery you can get something like

```
$('#id').change(function(){
    var lat = $(this).find(':selected').attr('data-lat');
    var long = $(this).find(':selected').attr('data-long');
});
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer, it might work!:) I'm trying to work out but still getting error with parsing ;/ I can display those 'lat' and 'lon' in value, but can't store in data-lat. Any idea why?

Comment: May i know how do you mean by that you couldnt store it ?

Comment: <html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      
        $('#test').change(function(){
            alert($(this).find(":selected").attr('lat'));
        });
  });
  </script>
  
</head>
<body>
<select id ="test">
  <option lat="1" value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option lat="2" value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option lat="3" value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option lat="4" value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
 </body>
</html>

Comment: There were some problems with all those "'. etc :P Now works fine, thank you! :)

Comment: Would love to but I don't have enough reputation points, I gave you a tick, I don't know if that helps or not, I'm new to stackoverflow. Regards! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$colors = array("red","green","blue","yellow");
?>
<select>
<?php 
foreach ($colors as $h)
   {
   echo "<option value=".$h.">".$h."</option>";
   }
?>   
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Have to add some attributes to option

```
foreach ($arajka as $a)
    {
        echo  "<option data-lat='" . $['lat'] . "' 
        data-lon='" . $['lon'] . "'
        value=\"" .$a['id']. "\">" .$a['id']. "_" . $a['name'] . "   </option>";
    }
        ?>
```

You can get data from attributes by 
    var lon = jQuery('#option-id').attr('data-lon');
and the same for lat